# Can Azure Sentinel aggregates data from devices running on-premises or in any cloud?

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-sentinel

**Can Azure Sentinel aggregates data from devices running on-premises?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out the microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/connect-data-sources

1. Default connectors can already ingest data from Windows Event logs and firewalls
2. External API's for Okta, Barracuda WAF, etc are there as well
3. Syslog data collected by an agent

Most/all of this can be done with the Log Analytics Agent